# Starling, hitTest: rotation and scale

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, starling-framework

I'm working on a game in which the shapes have to collide after changing rotation and size. As long as image1 isn't rotated using its .pivotX and .pivotY the hitTest works but as soon as I rotate around pivot the collision is wrong. I tried to use matrix but without good results.
Anyone can help me? Here the code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    import starling.core.Starling;
    import starling.display.Image;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;
    import starling.textures.Texture;
    import starling.textures.TextureAtlas;

    public class HitTest extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="src/image.png")]
        public static const ImagePng:Class;

        public function HitTest()
        {
            addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init():void{
            //First Image
            var bitmap1:Bitmap = new ImagePng();
            var texture1:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap1);
            var image1:Image = new Image(texture1);
            addChild(image1);
            /*
            Here's the problem:
            If you don't use .pivotX and .pivotY image1 doesn't rotate around its center but hits image2
            If you use .pivotX and .pivotY image1 rotates around its center but the hittest doesn't work.
            */
        //  image1.pivotX = image1.width/2;
        //  image1.pivotY = image1.height/2;
            image1.x=215;
            image1.y=50;
            image1.rotation=1;

            var rect1:Rectangle = image1.getBounds(this);
            var offset1:Matrix = new Matrix;

            offset1.rotate(1);

            offset1.tx = image1.x - rect1.x;
            offset1.ty = image1.y - rect1.y;

            var bitmapData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect1.width, rect1.height, true, 0);
            bitmapData1.draw(bitmap1, offset1); 

            //Second Image
            var bitmap2:Bitmap = new ImagePng();
            var texture2:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap2);
            var image2:Image = new Image(texture2);
            addChild(image2);
            image2.x=270;
            image2.y=-10;

            var rect2:Rectangle = image2.getBounds(this);

            var offset2:Matrix = new Matrix;
            offset2.tx = image2.x - rect2.x;
            offset2.ty = image2.y - rect2.y;    

            var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect2.width, rect2.height, true, 0);
            bitmapData2.draw(bitmap2, offset2); 

            var point1:Point = new Point(rect1.x, rect1.y);
            var point2:Point = new Point(rect2.x, rect2.y);

            //Hit Test
            if(bitmapData1.hitTest(point1,255,bitmapData2,point2,255))
            {
                image2.color=0x00ff00;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is again with matrix, but I think it works pretty well (it's somehow old, but the idea remains the same): http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/